# error: LOWORD undeclared

Tags: c++, winapi

I meet that problem:

LOWORD undeclared

with this piece of code:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (lParam==0)
            {
                if ((LOWORD)wParam==IDM_HELLO)
                   MessageBox(0, L"Hello", (LPCSTR)szClassName, MB_OK);
            }
        break;
        }
```

I don't know what I loss. Anyone help me?

Comment: `LOWORD` is a "function" macro. And I guarantee you that cast to `LPCSTR` is going to screw your text up.

Comment: Your use of `LOWORD` as if it were a type you could cast to, like `DWORD` makes me smile... it is the kind of mistake I know I would have made when I was starting out in WinAPI 20 years ago, long before there were Internet sites like this to help. Progress is wonderful. It is a macro, in case you were wondering - it gives you the low-order bytes of a `DWORD`.

Comment: @chris and when you use a function macro as an object, it is basically not recognized at all. You don't get a diagnostic that a function macro is being used wrong. This allows, for example, `(getchar)()` to call the real C function rather than the macro (if there is one) without having to `#undef getchar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOWORD` is not a type that you cast a variable to, but a macro to extract the lower 16 bits of a 32-bit value. Your code will probably compile if you change it to this:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if (lParam==0)
    {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDM_HELLO)
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"Hello", (LPCSTR)szClassName, MB_OK);
        }
    }
    break;
 }
```

Comment: **+1** This goes half-way to solving the problem... it is certainly better than trying to cast to `LOWORD`, but I think it might be worth mentioning that the macro is defined in `Windef.h`, which you would implicitly include by including `Windows.h`. It is hard to imagine a situation where `WM_COMMAND` is defined without including `Windows.h`, but you never know.